# jQuery load and datalist linkbutton not posting back

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am loading an aspx page into a div using jquery.load().  The aspx page loaded into the div has a datalist. Each datalist item has a linkbutton.  My problem is that the linkbutton is not causing a postback though.  Strangely, if I change the linkbutton to a button, it does postback.  Also, when loading the page normally (not from a jquery.load event), the linkbutton performs correctly.

What is it that causes the linkbutton to not cause a postback when loaded this way? And is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks in advance,

IUJPJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinkButton renders a __doPostBack() JS method call, whereas a Button renders a submit button by default.

When replacing the UI with JQuery.load, scripts inside the content do not automatically parse and run.  That's probably the issue here.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on what Brian said.
Is there a better way to handle it? I can think of a couple of ways:

1. convert the postback events to a handler. Then you can wire your dynamically loaded linkbuttons to regular links and use jquery ajax to post to your handler.
2. You could load your aspx page as an iframe

I think the 1st option is more elegant but requires more work.